# fetch data from two tables but only from first table sql

Tags: php, sql

i have two tables(foregin key) first is 'question' and second is 'answer' it's like a quiz. 'question' table have only question's and 'answer' tables have only options.
now i want to fetch data from both tables but from first table i want only one row (ex. id = 4) and from second table all the related rows(id=4). help for related query i also did sql joins.

Comment: `SELECT t1.id, t2.* FROM ......`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 USING(id) WHERE id = 4`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following SQL and enhance it as per your needs:-

```
SELECT question.column_name_1, question.column_name_2, option.column_name_3, option.column_name_4 from question, option WHERE question.id = option.question_id_column_name;
```

Comment: hello nandal Thanx for help,But i'm already did this query. now suppose 'question' table have only one row of id=4, and 'answer' table have 4 rows of id=4

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the clear scenario of your database tables , still I'm writing a query for you , if you have some other names for fields , please use those accordingly .

```
$sql = "select *
        from question as 'qst'
        inner join answer as 'ans'
        on ans.question_id = qst.id
        where qst.id = 1" ;
```

Use proper field names and you will get the desired output .